# HTTPerror 400 Invalid Upload Request: Trying Sample Code for upload file to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying the sample code from the Quickstart section of Google Drive API and I am getting the following error:\

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 60, in <module>
    file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 656, in execute
    _, body = self.next_chunk(http=http)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 789, in next_chunk
    return self._process_response(resp, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 816, in _process_response
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&alt=json returned "Invalid Upload Request">
```

I am using the sample code, no changes.  The same code worked yesterday, but today its not working..is this a server side bug?

Comment: {media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)} if this is your media_body, your file which you are trying to upload should also with same mimeType. {sgeorge-mn:google_drive sgeorge$ file document*
document.txt:  ASCII text
documents.txt: empty} In this case if you try to upload second file, you can't upload with your current media_body.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same error when specified nonexistent file. Please try to specify full path to uploading file.

Comment: I also encountered this error, but with an empty file.